# Is it possible to do serial communication with the device FT232?

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello

I want to make a serial communication with rosserial, adapted the converter FT232. Can you do this or this node only works with arduino?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34924/is-it-possible-to-do-serial-communication-with-the-device-ft232?/) by [andresiguano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1921/andresiguano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can; rosserial is a [general protocol](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Overview/Protocol) for  communication over RS232.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2